# Spring Boot AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext fail to populate autowired declared fields, which are in dynamic class

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, dynamic

There is a JUnit test as follow:

Memory compiler compiles a string to class on.the.fly.The report, which contains some @Autowired declared fields, like reportRepository etc.

Everything works as expected, the dynamic class report can use autowired fields implements its functionality.

When it is put in MVC environment, using `autowired` application context, which is AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext, `autowired` property value can't be populated.

with debug, `findCandidateNames` method `return []`, which should return an array containing field name as in test environment. Please refer to the regarding source code and give me some suggestion on it. Thanks.

```
results =  compiler.compile("Report.java", reportClassString);

Class<?> clazz = compiler.loadClass("on.the.fly.Report", results);

IReport report = (IReport) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(clazz);    
report.creatPdf(reportObject);
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'on.the.fly.AgreementReport':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'agreementReportProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.lims.api.report.domain.dto.AgreementReportProperties' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>     at
>   com.lims.api.sample.web.controller.AgreementController.downloadPdfFile(AgreementController.java:161)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

After a few days research, I got the root reason.
Just make my customized class loader as the child of spring context class loader, and then the dependency could be injected successfully.
the source code is as follow:

Class clazz = compiler.loadClass("on.the.fly.AgreementReport", 
    results,context.getClassLoader());